# Cucumber test redirect url against another url

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber

I am writing Cucumber tests.

In my code when clicking a button the button redirects to another page. The url for that page will always be the same. how do i get the current URL from the cucumber test? I tried

```
if (driver.getCurrentUrl() === http://localhost:8080/testURL){
      console.log("some output");
}
```

but it doesnt work.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: As it redirects to another page but the `url for that page will always be the same` try to wait for some unique element to be present on the new page then you can induce `for()` loop to validate the url.

Comment: what do you mean by current URL? if URL remains same, how do you manually identify which URL is which for page? you gotta do the same way in automation

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the current URL in the browser is:

`string currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();`

If you wish to define a URL in cucumber in a previous step and you want to use that URL in a future step, in the previous step add the URL to your scenario context.